# Accessing Gmail Password from Android Device Remotely

Tags: applications, gmail, nokia-5

I was using a Nokia 5 and I lost it over the weekend. I have the gmail app stored there that has sign ins to 3 of my emails
`s*****@gmail.com`, 
`r******@gmail.com` &
`r1*****@gmail.com`

Unfortunately I have no access to the last mailing address because apparently I forgot the password. It was a fairly new account so when I try to recover the password, google cannot verify its my account. The account is linked to my local bitcoins account therefore I cannot log in and have access to my bitcoins.

I have the following question, if I get a new phone and restore android, will the gmail app appear with the accounts logged on? and if not, is there a way for me to find out the password? I am not sure if this is allowed but I will spare some few bitcoins to the person who can help out.( if not allowed, I will edit and remove this part)

Comment: by the way its only logged on on the app and not on chrome

Answer (score 3):

> If i get a new phone and restore android, will the gmail app appear with the accounts logged on?

When you log in on your new phone using some account, only this account will be present on this device. To read mail from other accounts, you will need to sign in to those accounts as well.

> Is there a way for me to find out the password?

When you log in, your password is sent to Google servers, and they check if provided password is correct. If authentication passes, the server returns session token and no password is being stored on your phone. So **no, there is no way to find out the password**.